# How can I do variable object inside of function like jQuery do?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, object

I have this function to show notification

```
var notification_box = {
    notification: function (msg) {
        $('#notification_box').animate({
            top: "100"
        }).text(msg)
    }
}
```

and I'm declare it with

```
notification_box.notification("wwaaaa");
```

How to declare the function with this?

```
notification_box.notification({
    msg: "wwaaaa"
});
```

Answer (score 2):

By using dot notation or bracket notation.

You are passing an object to the function `notification` in the `object` `notification_box`. Within the function `msg` refers to the object you've passed. A property of that function is `msg`, so `msg.msg` (or `msg['msg']`) is the way to access the variable.

```js
var notification_box = {
  notification: function(msg) {
    $('#notification_box').animate({
      top: "100"
    }).text(msg.msg) //look at the dot notation here, it refers to the object
  }
}


notification_box.notification({
  msg: "wwaaaa"
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="notification_box"></div>
```

---

Even cooler is `defineProperty` using a `getter` and `setter`

```js
var notification_box = {"notify_message" : ""};

Object.defineProperty(notification_box, "notification", {
 get : function(){return this.notify_message;},
 set : function(value){ 
              $('#notification_box').animate({top: "100"}).text(value);
              this.notify_message = value;
              }
});

//set
notification_box.notification = "waaaaaaa";
//get
console.log(notification_box.notification);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="notification_box"></div>
```

Comment: i didnt realy understand that second method. but thanks :D

Answer (score 1):

Passing json to function can be accessed using dot notation

> object.attribute

In your case  use

```
msg.msg  #First msg is javascript object and second msg is attribute
```

Comment: "#First msg is json object and second msg is attribute", `json object`, it's a *JavaScript* object and not [tag:JSON]. That would be `{"msg" : "wwaaa"}`